# Vimscript Operator-Pending Mappings yields "Trailing characters" error

Tags: vim

I am trying to reproduce the example in chapter 15 of Steve Losh's "Learn Vimscript the Hard Way" (http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html), in the section called "Changing the Start."

First, I start vim with the following command:

```
vim -u NONE foo
```

to ensure that no plugins are loaded.
Next I type

```
print foo(bar)
```

in the buffer and then enter

```
:onoremap in( :<c-u>normal! f(vi(<cr>
```

Finally, I place the cursor over the "p" in "print" and enter `cin(`. The status line displays:

```
:<c-u>normal! f(vi(<cr>
```

with a blinking cursor at the end. I hit enter and the status line then displays:

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

The expected outcome, according to the book, is that vim will delete the contents of the parentheses and place you in insert mode between them.

Here is the version info:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May  2 2017 03:55:34)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-596
Compiled by Homebrew
```

Comment: Are you sure you ran everything exactly the way you typed it? When I try that, it works perfectly. Are `<c-u>` and `<cr>` control characters (i.e. `^U` and `^M`) or literal text?

Comment: I just went through and reproduced it a second time. I just updated my response with version info about vim. That might have some bearing.

Comment: Works for me as well, Vim 8.1.443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: use `vim -u DEFAULTS foo` instead.

That should keep Vim in `'nocompatible'` mode, which is needed for `<Key>` codes to be recognized in mappings.

---

The symptoms you describe are consistent to having [`<` included in `'cpoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#cpo-%3C), which is documented to:

> Disable the recognition of special key codes in `<>`    form in mappings, abbreviations, and the "to" part of   menu commands.  For example, the command `:map X <Tab>` results in `X` being mapped to "`<Tab>`"  (5 characters) when   `<` is included; but    "`^I`"   (`^I` is a real `<Tab>`) when `<` is excluded.

That is consistent with you getting the literal result of your mapping in your command-line, without proper expansion of the `<c-u>` and `<cr>` key codes.

The defaults for [`'cpoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cpoptions%27) are:

> Vim default: "aABceFs",
>   Vi default:  **all flags**

So this means `<` (along with all other flags) will be included by default in Vi mode, which is triggered when [`'compatible'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27compatible%27) is set (or, perhaps more accurately, when `'nocompatible'` is not set.)

It turns out that when you use [`-u NONE`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u) in your command-line starting Vim, it will start in `'compatible'` mode.

You can use instead `-u DEFAULTS`, which is quite similar to `-u NONE`, but it will still load the [`defaults.vim` script shipped with Vim runtime](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.1.1712/runtime/defaults.vim), which will among other things set `'nocompatible'`.

From [the docs](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-u):

> When `-u DEFAULTS` (all uppercase) is passed, this has the same effect as `-u NONE`, but the [`defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) script is loaded, which will also set `'nocompatible'`.
>
> Using the `-u` argument with another argument than `DEFAULTS` has the side effect that the `'compatible'` option will be on by default.  This can have unexpected effects.